# single point compact not closed how to show it

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Hello how to show the following:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space then a single point is compact but not
necessarily closed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $X$ be the [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space): $X=\{0,1\}$, and the open sets are $\varnothing,\{1\}$, and $X$. Is $\{1\}$ a compact set in $X$? Is it a closed set?

Answer (score 2):

Take $\Bbb{R}$ with the trivial topology. The set $\{0\}$ is compact but is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

The topological space $X$ is $T_1$ (i.e. for any two distinct points $x$, $y$, $x$ has an open neighbourhood that does not contain $y$) if and only if all single-point sets are closed.